# Advanced usage of explode()

Tags: php, explode

I want a user to enter their full name in a single field in an attempt to create a sleek UX.

```
$user = 'Robert John Alex Ridly';
$user = explode(' ', $user);
```

I want explode the string and allocate sections to variables

```
$first_name = $user[0];
$middle_names = ?
$last_names = $user[last]?;
```

Problem A - How do you target the last explode without knowing how many exploded 'pieces' there will be?

Problem B - Is there a way to target all pieces between the first and last and put them back together in a string adding the spaces back?

Comment: You could `array_pop($user)` for last_name and `array_shift($user)` for first_name, then if `$user` is not empty `implode(' ', $user)` for any middle name(s)?

Comment: You can know how many pieces there will be: `count($user);` = the amount of "pieces".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$user = explode(" ", $user); // create the array
$first_name = array_shift($user); // gets first element
$last_names = array_pop($user); // gets last element
$middle_names = implode(" ", $user); // re-unites the rest
```

Answer (score 1):

A. you can use `end()`

end() advances array's internal pointer to the last element, and returns its value.

B. you could do something like

```
foreach ($exploded as $key=>$value) {
   if ($key == 0 || $key == (count($exploded) -1)) continue;
   $middle_name_array[] = $value;
}

$middle_name = implode(' ', $middle_name_array);
```

there might be better solutions for problem B.

Answer (score 1):

Working example as explained in comment:

```
$user = 'Robert John Alex Ridly';
$user = explode(' ', $user);

// Gets first element in $user
$first_name = array_shift($user);

// Gets last element in $user (A)
$last_name = array_pop($user);

// Assign remaining names (B)
$middle_names = implode(" ", $user); // Or just assign $users array (It will only contain those middle names at this point)
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem A:

You can target the last item in array by using `$last_name = end($user)` The end() function tells php to get the last item in array.

Problem B:

You can use the `array_slice()` function in php.

> array_slice(array,start,length,preserve)
>
> length:   Optional. Numeric value. Specifies the length of the returned
>   array. If this value is set to a negative number, the function will
>   stop slicing that far from the last element. If this value is not set,
>   the function will return all elements, starting from the position set
>   by the start-parameter.
>
> preserve:     Optional. Specifies if the function should preserve or reset  keys.

so in your example it would be

```
$middle_names = implode(" ", array_slice($user,1,-1))
```

[W3Schools array_slice()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_slice.asp)

Comment: Pretty sure `$user[-1]` will throw an Undefined Index error.

Comment: Yeah, edited that. Have been programming python the last few days.

Comment: nice, yea php can be odd